# wanted to maintain the state of drop down menu in smaller wiondows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap for my navigation bar...
when i reduce the browser window you can see a button on the top....
when you click the button you would see a drop down menu....
but when i click the link inside the drop down menu....it will take to another page...but the drop down menu will collapse....
how to maintain the state of the drop down menu even when it moves to another page....

```
!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


 /* DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION
  * ========================= */

  var toggle = '[data-toggle=dropdown]'
    , Dropdown = function (element) {
        var $el = $(element).on('click.dropdown.data-api', this.toggle)
        $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () {
          $el.parent().removeClass('open')
        })
      }

  Dropdown.prototype = {

    constructor: Dropdown

  , toggle: function (e) {
      var $this = $(this)
        , $parent
        , isActive

      if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

      $parent = getParent($this)

      isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

      clearMenus()

      if (!isActive) {
        $parent.toggleClass('open')
      }

      $this.focus()

      return false
    }

  , keydown: function (e) {
      var $this
        , $items
        , $active
        , $parent
        , isActive
        , index

      if (!/(38|40|27)/.test(e.keyCode)) return

      $this = $(this)

      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()

      if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

      $parent = getParent($this)

      isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

      if (!isActive || (isActive && e.keyCode == 27)) {
        if (e.which == 27) $parent.find(toggle).focus()
        return $this.click()
      }

      $items = $('[role=menu] li:not(.divider):visible a', $parent)

      if (!$items.length) return

      index = $items.index($items.filter(':focus'))

      if (e.keyCode == 38 && index > 0) index--                                        // up
      if (e.keyCode == 40 && index < $items.length - 1) index++                        // down
      if (!~index) index = 0

      $items
        .eq(index)
        .focus()
    }

  }

  function clearMenus() {
    $(toggle).each(function () {
      getParent($(this)).removeClass('open')
    })
  }

  function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')
      , $parent

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') //strip for ie7
    }

    $parent = selector && $(selector)

    if (!$parent || !$parent.length) $parent = $this.parent()

    return $parent
  }


  /* DROPDOWN PLUGIN DEFINITION
   * ========================== */

  var old = $.fn.dropdown

  $.fn.dropdown = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('dropdown')
      if (!data) $this.data('dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }

  $.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown


 /* DROPDOWN NO CONFLICT
  * ==================== */

  $.fn.dropdown.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.dropdown = old
    return this
  }


  /* APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
   * =================================== */

  $(document)
    .on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
    .on('click.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
    .on('click.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
    .on('click.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
    .on('keydown.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)

}(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The page is reloaded to a new page, new content (including navbar) etc

Comment: The only way you can get the navigation to stay in place is if the new content to be loaded was on the same page, not in a new page.

Comment: can you tell the reason in technical way

Comment: The reason is the menu is which you are seeing on the screen is a HTML document that is rendered by your browser. When you navigate away from that page by clicking a link (in your case a link in the nav) then the current HTML document is discarded (and all of its contents) and the new HTML document is loaded and rendered by your browser. Your browser is unaware that the navigation is the same between the two documents etc, it treats them as new data. The only contradiction to this is that your browser will store cookies and images in a chache, this is non-related though.